# MATLAB: Setting up an optimization function

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I need guidance setting up my first optimization problem using the Optimization Toolbox.

I have a 3D surface model representing a long shirt sleeve. I have defined a cutting plane passing through the surface. The initial orientation of the plane was obtained by PCA: The 1st principal component of the surface model vertices defines the plane normal vector. My optimization is to orient the plane about plane vectors u,v (initially the 2nd and 3rd Prin. Comps) in order to minimize the cross section area of the intersection of the plane and the surface model. I would like to constrain the orientation to within X degrees of rotation about each of the 2 axes to narrow the solution space.

My questions are:

Can you recommend a particular solver for this case? Can I solve for both rotation angles (about u and v) simultaneously?

Should I be solving for the 3 components of the normal vector instead? (While applying the needed constraints)

Do I have to set up the objective function with a nested function to pass the surface model data, initial plane orientation, etc?

I'm struggling to find an example online similar to my case.

I appreciate any suggestions and apologize in advance for my naiveté.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with your particular example but most minimizers are reasonably similar and you just have to follow a bit of a framework to get the optimizer working.

This is some function minimization code which I tweaked to put up here but have used in the past. fmincon is a great general function minimizer and you can setup lots of different constraints on the parameters (bounds, equality constraints and inequality constraints).  It will not be the most efficient in all cases, but it might give you a good start.

Basically you want to create an initial guess, set the bounds and then call fmincon with a reference to the fitfun function.

```
function [t2, pd, offset] = t2fit(te, mm)

% Intial guess
x0 = [(-1/p(1))/fact, max(mm) 0]; % t2 pd

% Other constratints
A = []; B = []; Aeq = []; Beq = [];  

% Bounds
LB=[ 1/fact 0 -1 ]; UB = [ 1000/fact 1 1 ];

% Matlab options to the optimizer
opts = optimset('fmincon');
opts = optimset(opts, 'display', 'none');

%  Call the minimization routine 
x = fmincon(@fitfun, x0, A, B, Aeq, Beq, LB, UB, [], opts, te, mm);

% Get the output variables
t2 = x(1); 
pd = x(2); 
offset=x(3);

%%===================================================================
function dd = fitfun(x, te, mm)

%  The current value of the three input parameters
t2 = x(1);
pd = x(2);
offset = x(3);

%  Calculate the model curve
yy = pd .* exp( -te ./ t2 ) + offset;

%  Compute the error between the model curve the  
%  the measured curve -- dd is returned
dd = sqrt(sum( (yy-mm).^2 ));
```

Given your problem you might want to use lsqcurvefit or something like that.

Comment: Thank you brechmos! Your example helped a lot in formulating my functions. I really appreciate your input.